# writeToFile message doesn't work or produce a file in the set path

Tags: objective-c

Why doesn't this create a text file on my desktop? The error description is "null".

```
    NSString* path = @"/Users/amr/Desktop/test5.txt";
    NSError* error = nil;


    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"hello"];
    [data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

    NSLog(@"the error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last parameter of that "`writeToFile`" line to this:

```
[data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

And you might see something more informative.  Right now you're only passing in "`nil`", not a pointer to a `NSError *` object.

"`writeToFile:options:error:`" also returns a BOOL of YES on success and NO on failure (and that's when you can check what's been returned in the error parameter you're passing in).

As an aside, why are you trying to write to "`/Users/amr/`" via the Simulator?? (you tagged this question with an "iOS" tag)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did change it and it still logs the same result. As for the tag, I did it by mistake, sorry.

Comment: Another problem is that your NSData object is likely "`nil`", because your app is looking for a file named "`hello`" and you haven't specified a path to the file named "`hello`".

Comment: OH YES ! , I changed it now to have a path that contains my text and it did create "test5.txt" on my desktop. Many thank again !